# Extending a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have been able to present the first block of what I want. For this aim I wrote

```
Graph[
  {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3,  3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 
   1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4,   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4},
  VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}]
```

Therefore I had

[image]

For adding the next cell I modified the above graph by

```
Graph[
  {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 
   1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4,2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5}, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}}]
```

But I do not have the desired graph contained 6 vertices and 11 edges. How to reach that correctly!? What is wrong in the above code!?
Thankx in advance.

Comment: The rhs of the rule `VertexCoordinates -> ..` should have 6 elements (you have 7).

Comment: You are right...I corrected it in addition to modify `{1,2}` would be replaced by `{2,0}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can also try:

```
ClearAll[kingGraph]
kingGraph = Module[{vc = Tuples[Range /@ {#2, #}]}, 
    RelationGraph[ChessboardDistance[##] == 1 &, vc, 
     VertexCoordinates -> vc, ##3, VertexLabels -> None]] &;
```

or

```
ClearAll[kingGraph]
kingGraph[nr_, nc_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{vc = Tuples[Range /@ {nc, nr}]},
  RelationGraph[ChessboardDistance[##] == 1 &, vc, 
   VertexCoordinates -> vc, opts, VertexLabels -> None]]
```

***Examples:***

```
Row[kingGraph[2, #, ImageSize -> 1 -> 100, PlotLabel -> Row[{"dimensions: ", {2, #}}]] & /@
  {2, 3, 5}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

```
Row[kingGraph[3, #, ImageSize -> 1 -> 100, PlotLabel -> Row[{"dimensions: ", {3, #}}]] & /@ 
 {2, 3, 5}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

```
kingGraph[8, 8, ImageSize -> 1 -> 50, PlotLabel -> Row[{"dimensions: ", {8, 8}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful and Fantanstic

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want

```
Graph[
  {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1,
   1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6,4 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5}, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}}]
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain very clearly what you are trying to do. If you want to repeat that unit cell and create the corresponding graph, this is probably the easiest way.

```
NearestNeighborGraph[
 Tuples[Range[5], {2}],
 {All, Sqrt[2] + 0.1}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much.....Your code shows the perfectness of you. However I think the kglr's code is very close to what is in my mind.